# Проблема с повторным добавлением фрагментов во ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Есть ViewPager с фрагментами. Из него, удаляются и потом обратно добавляются фрагменты. У меня получается удалить и добавить фрагмент, но при выборе страницы во ViewPager - приложение падает падает на строке:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
```

с ошибкой:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: OutCallsFragment{1904c5cd #1 id=0x7f0e00a7}
```

Вот код активити с адаптером

```
    // ...

    private void initViewPager() {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (MyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        setupDefaultTabs();
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTabSelected position: " + tab.getPosition());

                //set current page in viewPager and page title
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                title.setText(adapter.getTitle(tab.getPosition()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if (drawerOn && tab.getPosition() != 0) {
                    navigationDrawer.removeFromTab(adapter.getTabItem(tab.getPosition()));
                    adapter.removeFragment(tab.getPosition());
                    adapter.removeTabItem(tab.getPosition());
                    tabLayout.removeTabAt(tab.getPosition());
                }
            }
        });

        setupTabIcons();
    }


    public void addTabItem(TabItem item){
        Log.d(TAG, "Fragment name: " + item.getFragment());
        Log.d(TAG, "Title name: "  + item.getTitle());
        adapter.addFragment(item.getFragment(), item.getTitle());
        adapter.addTabItem(item);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getTabCount()-1).setIcon(item.getIcon());
    }



    /**
     * Fragment adapter
     */

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private List<TabItem> tabItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addTabItem(TabItem tabItem){
            tabItemList.add(tabItem);
            addFragment(tabItem.getFragment(), tabItem.getTitle());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void removeFragment(int position) {
            if (!mFragmentList.isEmpty() && position < mFragmentList.size()) {
                mFragmentList.remove(position);
                mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        public String getTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

        public TabItem getTabItem(int position){
            Log.d(TAG, "TabList  size() = " + tabItemList.size());
            Log.d(TAG, "Tab position = " + position);
            return tabItemList.get(position);
        }

        public void removeTabItem(int position) {
            tabItemList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // return mFragmentTitleList.get(position); to display icons + text
            // return null to display only the icon
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

помимо удаления из списка нужно выполнить

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(<Фрагмен>).commit();
```